# Speed up Loops in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently using 2 if loops and a do loop to get my result. But this is proving to be extremely slow and usually crashing. The file is around 16MB. Secondly, it is not correctly changing the start date in Sheet 1 for all dates i.e. sometimes if the date is less than the Startofweek. It will still give the initial date.

In sheet "Leasing". Column A contains Car numbers, Column E contains the Start Date and Column F contains the End Date.
Sheet 1 will be where the results are needed. Column A the start date, B the end Date and C the Car number.

I need it to give me the car number in Sheet 1:
i) If car number is not blank then

1. if the end date in Leasing is blank.
   a) End date in Sheet 1 would be Endofweek(inputted by user)
   b) Start date in Sheet 1would be Startofweek(inputted by user) or Start Date(Leasing). Whichever is greater.
2. if end date is less than Endofweek but greater than startofweek.
   a) End date in Sheet 1 would be EndDate leasing
   b) Start date in Sheet 1would be Startofweek(inputted by user) or Start Date(Leasing). Whichever is greater.

Column D of Sheet 1 then contains the difference between End of week and Start of week(Column B - Column A)

Example: Startofweek: 22/3/21, Endofweek: 28/3/21
[image]

'''

```
Sub active_leasing_cars()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Const Leasing_start = 5 'Column leasing start from Leasing Hisaab
Const Leasing_end = 6 'Column Leasing start from leasing Hisaab
Const Leasing_car = 1
Const TARGET = "Sheet1"
Const LEASING = "Leasing Hisaab"
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsResult, wsLeasing As Worksheet
Dim i, j, iLastrow As Integer
Dim Endofweek, Startofweek As String



Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Set wsResult = wb.Sheets(TARGET)
Set wsLeasing = wb.Sheets(LEASING)
iLastrow = wsLeasing.Cells(Rows.Count, Leasing_car).End(xlUp).Row
i = 1
j = 2
Endofweek = InputBox("Please enter end date", "Enter Date", Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy"))
Startofweek = InputBox("Please enter start date ", "Enter Date", Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy"))
Do
i = i + 1
If wsLeasing.Cells(i, Leasing_car) = "" Then
If wsLeasing.Cells(i, Leasing_end) = "" Then
wsResult.Cells(j, 2) = Endofweek
If wsLeasing.Cells(i, Leasing_start) <= Startofweek Then
wsResult.Cells(j, 1).Value = Startofweek
Else: wsResult.Cells(j, 1) = wsLeasing.Cells(i, Leasing_start)
End If

ElseIf wsLeasing.Cells(i, Leasing_end) >= Startofweek And wsLeasing.Cells(i, Leasing_end) <= Endofweek Then
wsResult.Cells(j, 2) = wsLeasing.Cells(i, Leasing_end)
If wsLeasing.Cells(i, Leasing_start) <= Startofweek Then
wsResult.Cells(j, 1) = Startofweek
Else: wsResult.Cells(j, 1) = wsLeasing.Cells(i, Leasing_start)
End If
End If
wsResult.Cells(j, 3) = wsLeasing.Cells(i, Leasing_car)
wsResult.Cells(j, 4) = DateDiff("d", wsResult.Cells(j, 1), wsResult.Cells(j, 2))
j = j + 1
End If
Loop While i < iLastrow
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Some data input and expected output would be helpful indeed. Also, in other question you've posted, you never said anything about right or worng answers.

Comment: Perhaps, use an Excel formula?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I have added the information you have suggested.

Comment: Furthermore, I created a new Workbook to help with processing the information but I'm still stuck where all my values are not being read i.e. if the end Date is less than the endofweek. It is still showing the end date.

Comment: I'd recommend you indent your logic blocks - it makes code far easier to read.

Comment: I don't get any output since this line `If wsLeasing.Cells(i, Leasing_car) = "" Then` skips all the cars.

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't take too long. You've no formulae in your worksheets do you?

You could disable display updates and the automatic calculations via the below at the start of your macro, and see how you go:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

(don't forget to reenable at the end)

If that doesn't help, then a bit more work is required - I'd advise loading your data into a 2D array though and going from there.

```
Dim leasingData()

iRows = 0    
Do Until  isEmpty(Sheets("Leasing").cell(2+iRows,1))
    redim preserve leasingData(2, iRows)
    leasingData(0, iRows) = Sheets("Leasing").Cells(2 + iRows, 1)
    leasingData(1, iRows) = Sheets("Leasing").Cells(2 + iRows, 5)
    leasingData(2, iRows) = Sheets("Leasing").Cells(2 + iRows, 6)

    iRows = iRows = 1
Loop
```

Then from there, your searching and indexing should be much faster. The slowest part of VBA is interacting with the worksheets.

```
for iCar = 0 to ubound(leasingData,2)
    if leasingData(2, iCar) = "" then
        'No end date specified for this car, sub in end of week
    end if
    if leasingData(1, iCar) <= Start of week then
        'The car leaase started before the start of this week, so update to start of week
    end if 

next iCar
```

etc etc

Then you can push the data out of the array onto your result sheet:

```
for iCar = 0 to ubound(leasingData,2)
    Sheets("Target").cells(1+iCar, 3) = leasingData(0, iCar)
    Sheets("Target").cells(1+iCar, 1) = leasingData(1, iCar)
    Sheets("Target").cells(1+iCar, 2) = leasingData(2, iCar)
next iCar
```

In terms of your end of week update problem:

```
ElseIf wsLeasing.Cells(i, Leasing_end) >= Startofweek And wsLeasing.Cells(i, Leasing_end) <= Endofweek Then
    wsResult.Cells(j, 2) = wsLeasing.Cells(i, Leasing_end)
```

Will never do what you want it to, you need to replace the RHS with Endofweek

Comment: You can eliminate your read/write loops because you read a worksheet range into a 2D array (and the reverse) in a single step. `Dim myArray as variant : myArray = myRange`.  For the reverse, you have to ensure that `myRange` is the correct size. See[Arrays and Ranges in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

Comment: Agreed Ron - done that before myself and it works well - I've never done it when the ranges aren't continuous though. Is that possible?  [and did write out by looping this time as the order of columns is reversed - although I suppose if I was more careful in my setting up of the array to start with, I could have worked around that]

Comment: You are correct about non-contiguous arrays. They result in a jagged array; harder to loop. But looking at the code quickly, I would have thought you could create two arrays for the input (col 1 and col 5-6); then do the calculations into one for the output.

Answer (score 0):

You date comparison does not work properly because you have declared `Startofweek As String`. As a result `wsLeasing.Cells(i, Leasing_start) <= StartOfWeek` is `False` when the date `28/07/2020` is compared to the string `22/03/2021`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub active_leasing_cars()

    Const Leasing_start = 5 'Column leasing start from Leasing Hisaab
    Const Leasing_end = 6 'Column Leasing start from leasing Hisaab
    Const Leasing_car = 1
    Const TARGET = "Sheet1"
    Const LEASING = "Leasing Hisaab"

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsResult, wsLeasing As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, iLastrow As Long
    Dim EndOfWeek As Date, StartOfWeek As Date, s As String
    Dim ar, t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
     
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsResult = wb.Sheets(TARGET)
    Set wsLeasing = wb.Sheets(LEASING)
    iLastrow = wsLeasing.Cells(Rows.Count, Leasing_car).End(xlUp).Row

    ' end of week
    s = InputBox("Please enter end date dd/mm/yyyy", "Enter END Date", Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy"))
    If IsDate(s) Then
        ar = Split(s, "/")
        EndOfWeek = DateSerial(ar(2), ar(1), ar(0))
    Else
        MsgBox s & " is not a date", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

   ' start of week
    s = InputBox("Please enter START date ", "Enter Start Date dd/mm/yyyy", Format(EndOfWeek - 6, "dd/mm/yyyy"))
    If IsDate(s) Then
        ar = Split(s, "/")
        StartOfWeek = DateSerial(ar(2), ar(1), ar(0))
    Else
        MsgBox s & " is not a date)", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' sanity check
    If StartOfWeek > EndOfWeek Then
       MsgBox "Start: " & StartOfWeek & " after End: " & EndOfWeek, vbCritical
       Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim sCar As String, dtStart As Date, dtEnd As Date, val As Variant
    j = 1 ' sheet1 row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 2 To iLastrow
        sCar = wsLeasing.Cells(i, Leasing_car).Value
        If Len(sCar) > 0 Then
            ' check start date
            val = wsLeasing.Cells(i, Leasing_start).Value
            If Len(val) > 0 Then
                dtStart = val
            Else
                MsgBox "Start date is blank", vbCritical, "Row " & i
            End If
            
            ' End Dates
            val = wsLeasing.Cells(i, Leasing_end).Value
            If Len(val) = 0 Then
              'if the end date in Leasing is blank.
              'a) End date in Sheet 1 would be Endofweek(inputted by user)
                 dtEnd = EndOfWeek
            Else
                 dtEnd = val
            End If

            ' filter for dates
            If dtEnd < StartOfWeek Or dtStart > EndOfWeek Then
                ' ignore as either already ended or not started yet
            Else
                'b) Start date in Sheet 1 would be Startofweek(inputted by user)
                '   or Start Date(Leasing). Whichever is greater.
                If dtStart > StartOfWeek Then
                    wsResult.Cells(j, 1) = dtStart
                Else
                    wsResult.Cells(j, 1) = StartOfWeek
                End If
                wsResult.Cells(j, 2) = dtEnd
                wsResult.Cells(j, 3) = sCar
                wsResult.Cells(j, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]-RC[-3]"
                j = j + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
    wsResult.Columns("B:C").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox j - 1 & " records found for " & StartOfWeek & " to " & EndOfWeek, _
           vbInformation, Int(Timer - t0) & " seconds"
End Sub
```